# Want to draw a wireframe mesh over a solid 3d object imported from blender

Tags: c++, opengl

So I have this creature and I want to have three distinct modes, a solid, a wireframe and both. All examples using glOffset did not seem to work for me.

Here's my display:

```
// This function is called to display the scene.
void display()
{   
    //Background color
    glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    // Matrix setup
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(40, (float)width / (float)height, 0.1, 1000);

    // Matrix setup
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0, 0, -3);


    //draw object
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        for (int i = 0; i<mesh->nfaces.size(); i += 1)
            for (int j = 0; j<3; j += 1){
                glNormal3f(mesh->normal[mesh->nfaces[i][j]][0],
                mesh->normal[mesh->nfaces[i][j]][1],
                mesh->normal[mesh->nfaces[i][j]][2]);

                glVertex3f(mesh->vertex[mesh->faces[i][j]][0],
                mesh->vertex[mesh->faces[i][j]][1],
                mesh->vertex[mesh->faces[i][j]][2]);
            }
    glEnd();



    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Keyboard code where I tried to implement the shenanigans:

```
void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    float colorBronzeDiff[4] = { 0.8, 0.6, 0.0, 1.0 };
    switch (key)
    {
        case(27) :
            exit(0);
            break;
        case('s') :
        {
                      int myFlagCtr = getFlagCtr();
                      cout << "Pressed Before: " << getFlagCtr() << endl;
                      if (myFlagCtr == 0) {
                          glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);


                          setFlagCtr(1);
                      }
                      else if (myFlagCtr == 1) {
                          glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);

                            setFlagCtr(2);
                      } 
                      else if (myFlagCtr == 2) {
                          glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
                          glEnable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);
                          glPolygonOffset(1.0f, 1.0f);
                          glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
                          // draw
                            glDisable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);


                            glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
                            //glEnable( GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_LINE );
                            //glPolygonOffset( -2.0f, -2.0f );
                            glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
                            glLineWidth(1.0f);
                            // draw
                            //glDisable( GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_LINE );
                            setFlagCtr(0);

                          cout << "Pressed Before: " << getFlagCtr() << endl;
                      }
                      break;
        }
    }
}
```

And here's main:

```
void main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    // GLUT initialization.
    glutInit(&argc, argv);  
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(width, height);
    glutCreateWindow("CodeBase");

    // Register call backs.
    initialize();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshapeMainWindow);
    glutMotionFunc(mouse_motion);
    glutIdleFunc(idle);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse_button);

    // Enter GLUT loop.
    glutMainLoop();

    delete mesh;
}
```

I assume what I am supposed to do is draw the image twice and then offset it, but for the life of me I can't seem to get this to work. I can't get it to show such a mode by default by putting it directly in display and attempting to draw the object twice.

Edit: In response to latest answer.

```
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
glEnable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);
glPolygonOffset(1.0f, 1.0f);
glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
// draw
//draw object
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    for (int i = 0; i<mesh->nfaces.size(); i += 1)
        for (int j = 0; j<3; j += 1){
            glNormal3f(mesh->normal[mesh->nfaces[i][j]][0],
            mesh->normal[mesh->nfaces[i][j]][1],
            mesh->normal[mesh->nfaces[i][j]][2]);

            glVertex3f(mesh->vertex[mesh->faces[i][j]][0],
            mesh->vertex[mesh->faces[i][j]][1],
            mesh->vertex[mesh->faces[i][j]][2]);
        }
glEnd();
glDisable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);

glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glLineWidth(1.0f);
// draw
//draw object
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
for (int i = 0; i<mesh->nfaces.size(); i += 1)
for (int j = 0; j<3; j += 1){
    glNormal3f(mesh->normal[mesh->nfaces[i][j]][0],
        mesh->normal[mesh->nfaces[i][j]][1],
        mesh->normal[mesh->nfaces[i][j]][2]);

    glVertex3f(mesh->vertex[mesh->faces[i][j]][0],
        mesh->vertex[mesh->faces[i][j]][1],
        mesh->vertex[mesh->faces[i][j]][2]);
}
glEnd();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the image to render in both wireframe and solid mode you have to actually execute the geometry rendering functions (eg: `glBegin() ... glEnd()`) twice.

In your third setting in the keyboard callback you call

```
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
```

But you don't draw any geometry between those two calls. GL is a state machine so only the last change to a given state (in this case the polygon drawing mode) will impact the rendering.

your `setFlagCtr` call should be in the keyboard callback function, but all the other stuff should be in the draw function where for the wire + solid mode you'll have to make sure you're calling this section at least twice:

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
...
glEnd();
```

Long story short, don't put GL state or rendering management calls anywhere but your display function.